# How to fetch the data for the current hour in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to fetch data from a Django model while filtering its `DateTimeField()` to the current date and current hour.

models.py

```
class Log(models.Model):
    DATE                    =   models.DateTimeField()
    TYPE                    =   models.CharField(max_length=32,primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table='LOG'
        indexes=[
                models.Index(fields=['DATE','TYPE'])
                ]
```

views.py

```
obj=Log.objects.filter()
```

How can I define my filter in such a way that it returns the data of current hour only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter by the current hour and by current date you can use [`__date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#date) and [`__hour`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#hour) filters:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
obj=Log.objects.filter(DATE__date=now.date(), DATE__hour=now.hour)
```